# select latest record for each battery using SQL with count

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
BatteryId   TimeStamp                    Temprature
1           2017-02-13 12:16:14.000      23
1           2016-02-13 12:13:14.000      21
1           2015-01-13 12:16:14.000      19
2           2017-02-11 12:16:14.000      22
2           2016-02-13 12:16:14.000      16
3           2017-02-13 11:16:14.000      12
3           2016-02-13 12:15:14.000      25
```

I have table with multiple records for each battery as above
following sql query is returning latest record for each battery

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT BatteryId, Timestamp, Temperature
ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY BatteryId ORDER BY timestamp DESC)
AS N FROM tblBattery) AS TT WHERE N = 1
```

as

```
BatteryId   TimeStamp                    Temprature
1           2017-02-13 12:16:14.000      23
2           2017-02-11 12:16:14.000      22
3           2017-02-13 11:16:14.000      12
```

How I can add Count for each BatteryId, Here is what I need

```
BatteryId   TimeStamp                    Temprature   Count
1           2017-02-13 12:16:14.000      23           3
2           2017-02-11 12:16:14.000      22           2 
3           2017-02-13 11:16:14.000      12           2
```

Comment: i removed the mysql tag as the syntax looks like sql-server.

Comment: Is there a question here?

Comment: Yes definitely see the answer below from  Tajinder

Answer (score 2):

Use the `count` window function.

```
SELECT * FROM 
(SELECT BatteryId, Timestamp, Temperature,
 ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY BatteryId ORDER BY timestamp DESC) AS N,
 COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY BatteryId) as Cnt
 FROM tblBattery) TT 
WHERE N = 1
```

Comment: I think answer you pasted and mine is same. There is a little difference of time when we pasted the answer.

Comment: This  is copy of Tajinder answer

Comment: fyi..this answer was posted 40 seconds before the other..you can sort the page by oldest to check out.

Comment: @sumit I don't think this answer is copied. "@vkp" and me pasted the same solution, may be this is the easy solution for mentioned problem

Comment: @sumit This is not a copy of @Tajinder's answer. @vkp answered at `2017-02-13 22:13:26Z` and @Tajinder answered at `2017-02-13 22:14:02Z`. @vkp answered 36 seconds before @Tajinder, so he couldn't have copied... Unless..... @vkp are you secretly a time traveler from the future who has come to the past to gain some extra points?

Answer (score 1):

Hoping, i understood your problem correctly.

Please check if below query can help you.

```
SELECT *
FROM
  (SELECT BatteryId,
    TIMESTAMP,
    Temperature ,  ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY BatteryId ORDER BY TIMESTAMP DESC) AS N ,
    COUNT(0) OVER(PARTITION BY BatteryId ) CNT
  FROM tblBattery
  ) AS TT
WHERE N = 1;
```

Comment: @SqlZim yes, Thanks. Updated now.

Comment: Thanks @Tajinder that's exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: You should mark this answer as correct, the second answer is just a copy of first.

Answer (score 0):

Add a sub query before you perform the PARTITION BY

```
SELECT * 
FROM (SELECT 
         BatteryId
        ,Timestamp
        ,Temperature
        ,Count
        ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY BatteryId ORDER BY timestamp DESC) AS N
FROM (SELECT *, COUNT(BatteryId) As Count FROM tblBattery GROUP BY BatteryId)) AS TT WHERE N = 1
```

This should solve your issue.